# Overwritten NSScrollView.scrollWheel(with:) method disables vertical scroll

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsscrollview

I am using a custom `NSScrollView` class to detect horizontal scrolling in a vertical NSScrollView.

To do so my custom class overrides the `scrollWheel` method, and of course calls the super method as well. For some reason the vertical scroll doesn't work anymore although I am not modifying any of the event's data or returning anything. I am using the code below:

```
override func scrollWheel(with event: NSEvent) {
    if (self.lastDelta == 0 || (self.lastDelta < 10.0 && self.lastDelta > -10)) {
        if (event.scrollingDeltaX < CGFloat(-10.0)) {
            if (self.lastDelta == 0.0 || event.scrollingDeltaX < self.lastDelta) {
                vc?.swiped(direction: 1)
            }
        } else if (event.scrollingDeltaX > CGFloat(10.0)) {
            if (self.lastDelta == 0.0 || event.scrollingDeltaX > self.lastDelta) {
                vc?.swiped(direction: -1)
            }
        }
    }
    self.lastDelta = event.scrollingDeltaX
    return super.scrollWheel(with: event)
}
```

Calling the `super.scrollWheel(with: event)` (without return) at the beginning of the method doesn't make any difference. As soon as I remove the overwritten method above, the vertical scrolling works just fine.

Comment: See [Responsive Scrolling in AppKit Release Notes OS X 10.9](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/index.html#10_9Scrolling) "Do not override -scrollWheel: in an NSScrollView"

Comment: @Willeke Thanks for your reply. I managed to observe the NSScrollView.didLiveScrollNotification, but in the parameter passed to my observing method is no information about the scrolling delta, etc. Do you know a way to determine if the user tried to scroll horizontally?